# Spring Cacheable measure hit/miss with AspectJ

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-cache

I am using Spring Cache framework for caching and AspectJ to help measure stats about my app. I'm wondering how can I use AspectJ to determine when `@Cacheable` is retrieves the result from the cache?

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) describing your situation, the current vs. the expected behaviour. What have you tried so far with Spring AOP or AspectJ? Which are your difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

I believe statistics for Ehcache are enabled by default since 2.7 version. Statistics are exposed via jmx. Here is the javadoc stating the same: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheFactoryBean.html#setSampledStatisticsEnabled-boolean-

Comment: Is there no other way to get it as the method is called? Like when a method with Cacheable is called I can know if it retrieves the element from the cache.